# How to decode json object having attribute with multiple values in java?

Tags: java, json

this is my json object in javascript that i want to parse in java

```
var param{
  "attrib1":"abc",
  "attrib2":["x","y","z"]
}
```

I'm using jackson library. I am not able to retrieve the members of attrib2. How to do it? help

Comment: is this Java or JavaScript ? - to me this looks like JS.. Anyway in Java you can use JSon Parser

Comment: Depends on which JSON library you use

Comment: I recomand  Gson or Jackson libraries. Help you a lot, and are good documented and mature  libs.

Comment: Post your code. Jackson will usually map that onto a Java array or collection type with no problems.

Answer (score 0):

To get element from JSON Object you can do this

```
JSONObject json = (JSONObject)new JSONParser().parse(yourString);
System.out.println("attrib2=" + json.get("attrib2"));
```

Answer (score 0):

attrib2 is JsonArray so please get jsonArray.

```
jsonObject.optJSONArray("attrib2");
```